# Convert integer to binary string, padded with leading zeros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create new method Integer#to_bin that convert decimal to a binary string. The argument of #to_bin is the number of digits.  The result should be padded with leading zeros to make it have that many digits.

Example:

```
1.to_bin(4)
#=> "0001"
1.to_bin(3)
#=> "001"
1.to_bin(2)
#=> "01"
7.to_bin(1)
#=> nil
7.to_bin
#=> "111"
etс.
```

What I've tried:

```
class Integer

    def to_bin(number=nil)
        if number == nil
          return self.to_s(2)
        else 
          s = self.to_s(2).size
          e = number-s
          one = '0'
          two = '00'
          three = '000'

        if e==one.size
          one+self.to_s(2)
        elsif e==two.size
          two+self.to_s(2)
        elsif e==three.size
          three+self.to_s(2)
        end
        end
    end
end
```

**How do I convert an integer to a binary string padded with leading zeros?**

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to do?

Comment: convert decimal to binary

Comment: Doesn't `to_s(2)` work?

Comment: No, you're not trying to convert decima; to bin, you try to do some black magic. I'm asking what is that exactly. (to convert dec to bin `to_s(2)` is enough)

Comment: i want to add left-pad it with zeroes

Comment: Like Chris Heald writed

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The appropriate way to do this is to use Kernel's [`sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) formatting:

```
'%03b' % 1 # => "001"
'%03b' % 2 # => "010"
'%03b' % 7 # => "111"

'%08b' % 1 # => "00000001"
'%08b' % 2 # => "00000010"
'%08b' % 7 # => "00000111"
```

But wait, there's more!:

```
'%0*b' % [3, 1] # => "001"
'%0*b' % [3, 2] # => "010"
'%0*b' % [3, 7] # => "111"

'%0*b' % [8, 1] # => "00000001"
'%0*b' % [8, 2] # => "00000010"
'%0*b' % [8, 7] # => "00000111"
```

So defining a method to extend Fixnum or Integer is easy and cleanly done:

```
class Integer
  def to_bin(width)
    '%0*b' % [width, self]
  end
end

1.to_bin(8) # => "00000001"
0x55.to_bin(8) # => "01010101"
0xaaa.to_bin(16) # => "0000101010101010"
```

Answer (score 16):

Ruby already has a built-in mechanism to convert a number to binary: `#to_s` accepts a base to convert to.

```
30.to_s(2) # => "11110"
```

If you want to left-pad it with zeroes:

```
30.to_s(2).rjust(10, "0") => "0000011110"
```

You could extend this into a little method that combines the two:

```
class Fixnum
  def to_bin(width = 1)
    to_s(2).rjust(width, "0")
  end
end

> 1234.to_bin
=> "10011010010"
> 1234.to_bin(20)
=> "00000000010011010010"
```

Comment: `String#rjust` would be a little cleaner - `30.to_s(2).rjust(10, "0")`

Comment: Ah, good point. I was looking for #format since I *knew* there was some way to right-justify with the string as the receiver!

Comment: This does not give `nil` to `7.to_bin(1)`.

Comment: I presumed that was a bug, since it wasn't actually specified in the requirements as far as I can tell.

Comment: It looks like the expected behavior is to return `nil` when the argument is given and is less than the string length in binary before padding. In addition, the OPs code returns `nil` when the argument is other than 1, 2, or 3. I am not sure whether that was intended. But the question is badly phrased. It is mostly the OP's fault.